# Are questions about corpora for machine translation training on topic here?

Tags: discussion

I am interested in machine translations, especially [moses machine translation](http://www.statmt.org/moses/index.php?n=Main.HomePage).

For this I would need a language model for the target language. To create a language model the software analyses large corpus. Are questions about this welcome here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asking for resources can be okay, but it has the potential to be a list question, which aren't. And existing corpuses are generally easy to search for, so it will be hard to ask a good question about them.

Asking questions about how to develop your own corpus would be better.

Comment: How would a user know that "list questions" are out of bounds? Alternatively, how would a user know what a "list question" is?

Comment: It's standard across all of Stack Exchange: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124450 They aren't always off-topic (we allow list-of-languages questions here), but they are rarely *good* questions.

Comment: We have very many un-closed list questions. IMO the help center should point to the higher-level prohibition, wherever that is stated.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can ask about it: computational linguistics is on-topic here. But I am not sure how many users here are comfortable answering questions on this topic; I am not.